# How to manipulate with css class in angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

In my `AngularJS` `application` I want to give my users the ability to choose different `background-color` for the `header` and `navigation`, so they can customize it to their liking. A bit like a very simple `CMS`.

I have added some color pickers, [Angular-color-picker](https://github.com/ruhley/angular-color-picker), in the application, so they more easily can choose valid colors.

The different components that the users are gonna be able to change `background-color` have different [Bootstrap 3.3.5](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) `classes` (in this example it's `bg-dark`).

Right now I'm using a `$watch` in my `controller` that generates some `css styling` where I have the different `classes` which need to change values. This is then appended to the body.

This is a really ugly way to do it, but at the moment it has been the only way I have been able to accomplish what I want. I'm therefor asking for your help and guidance to see if somebody could tell me of a much better way? Or maybe point me in the right direction?

**Header view**

```
    <div id="navbar-brand" class="navbar-header {{navbarHeaderColor}}">
       <a ui-sref="lb.dashboard" class="navbar-brand text-lt">
          <img class="m-mid" ng-src="{{ organization_logo }}" alt="logo">
       </a>
       <div class="collapse navbar-collapse lb-navbar navbar-right">
           <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
               <li class="dropdown" dropdown>
                   <a href class="dropdown-toggle" dropdown-toggle>
                      User name
                   </a>
                   <ul class="dropdown-menu animated fadeInRight w p-none">
                       <li><a ui-sref="settings">Settings</a></li>
                       <li><a ui-sref="profile({user_id: user.id})">Profil</a></li>
                       <li class="divider m-t-none m-b-none"></li>
                       <li><a ng-click="logOut();">Log out</a></li>
                   </ul>
               </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**Controller**

```
$scope.navbarHeaderColor = 'bg-dark';

$scope.$watch('app.color', function (newValue, oldValue) {
    if (newValue) {
        var usercss =
            '#navbar-brand.bg-dark{background-color:' + newValue +' !important}' +
            '#navbar-brand.bg-dark a{' +
                'color: #FFFFFF !important' +
        '}';

        var css = document.createElement("style");
        css.type = "text/css";
        css.innerHTML = usercss;
        document.body.appendChild(css);
    }
}, true);
```

**Update**
Sorry, I totally forgot to mention that I also have tried to use `ng-style` (like 'user2971994' mentions).

**Header view**

```
    <div class="navbar-header" ng-style="{'background' : ''+ app.color.logo + ', color: ''+ app.color_text +''}">
        <a ui-sref="lb.dashboard" class="navbar-brand text-lt">
            <img class="m-mid" ng-src="{{ user.organization.logo }}" alt="{{ user.organization.name }}">
        </a>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse lb-navbar navbar-right">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="dropdown" dropdown>
                    <a href class="dropdown-toggle" dropdown-toggle>
                        User name
                    </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu animated fadeInRight w p-none">
                        <li><a ui-sref="settings">Settings</a></li>
                        <li><a ui-sref="profile({user_id: user.id})">Profil</a></li>
                        <li class="divider m-t-none m-b-none"></li>
                        <li><a ng-click="logOut();">Log out</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

In this case I have the challenges that the text inside, doesn't get affected. Event though I have also added `color` in my `ng-style`.

Comment: make sure you don't overwrite your `ng-style` with a `!important` in the already defined CSS

Comment: maybe you should use `!important` inside your `ng-style` to make sure that the a-tag color gets overwritten - otherwise you need to add `ng-style` to every a-tag ..

Answer (score 0):

You should use ng-style directive instead, where you can directly link the value of a scope variable with the css style.

In your case:

```
<div id="navbar-brand" class="navbar-header" ng-style="{'background-color':app.color}">
```

You can read more here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngStyle

Comment: Sorry I totally forgot to mention it, but I have tried with ng-style. I have updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to take a look at the [ngStyle](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngStyle) directive.  It allows you to set css style values based on a scope variable, for example:

```
<span ng-style="{color: app.color}"></span>
```

would set the div's color to the current value of the scope variable app.color.

Comment: Same goes for you, sorry I forgot to mention it, but I have tried with ng-style. I have updated my question.

Comment: I'm not sure which text you're referring to, but I would make a separate ng-style directly on the element whose text you want to color, rather than on the parent 'navbar=header' div

Comment: Also I'd double check your syntax on the ng-style- you don't need all those single quotes and plus signs to put in a scope variable, just imitate the examples in these two answers

Comment: @lt3: The code I added was just an simplified example. I will have some links in an ul. Regarding my ng-style syntax, you were totally right, I did't need the quotes and plus signs. Thanks!